# Render CDN fontawesome icons in self-contained R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, font-awesome, knitr

I am trying to add Font Awesome icons in a rmarkdown document and render it to an HTML file. I included the Font Awesome CDN CSS link in the footer and included it in the document using the `includes` argument. The icons could show when the `self_contained` YAML argument is set to `false`.

However, when `self_contained` is set to `true`, the icons do not show.

##### Rendered HTML document with `self_contained: false`

[image]

##### Rendered HTML document with `self_contained: true`

[image]

#### Sample documents

rmarkdown

````
---
title: "Test for fontawesome icon"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: true
    includes:
      after_body: samplefooter.html
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE)
```

Testing whether fontawesome icons could be shown

<!-- solid style -->
<i class="fas fa-user"></i>

<!-- regular style -->
<i class="far fa-user"></i>

<!--brand icon-->
<i class="fab fa-github-square"></i>
````

HTML Footer (`samplefooter.html`)

```html
<footer>
  <br>
  <!-- Add fa icon library -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" /> -->

  <hr />

  <p style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="" title="icon 1" class="fas fa-globe-asia"></a>
    <a href="" title="icon 2" class="fab fa-github"></a>
    <a href="" title="icon 3" class="fas fa-envelope"></a>
  </p>

  <br>
</footer>
```

---

xfun::session_info()

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS 12.3.1, RStudio 2022.2.3.492

Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8

Package version:
  askpass_1.1        base64enc_0.1.3    bslib_0.2.5.1      cachem_1.0.5       callr_3.7.0        cli_3.1.0          colorspace_2.0-2  
  commonmark_1.7     compiler_4.1.0     cpp11_0.4.2        crayon_1.4.2       curl_4.3.2         digest_0.6.29      ellipsis_0.3.2    
  evaluate_0.14      fansi_0.5.0        farver_2.1.0       fastmap_1.1.0      fs_1.5.0           fst_0.9.4          glue_1.5.1        
  graphics_4.1.0     grDevices_4.1.0    highr_0.9          htmltools_0.5.2    httpuv_1.6.1       httr_1.4.2         jquerylib_0.1.4   
  jsonlite_1.7.2     kableExtra_1.3.4   knitr_1.36         labeling_0.4.2     later_1.2.0        lifecycle_1.0.1    magrittr_2.0.1    
  methods_4.1.0      mime_0.12          munsell_0.5.0      openssl_1.4.5      packrat_0.7.0      parallel_4.1.0     pillar_1.6.4      
  pkgconfig_2.0.3    processx_3.5.2     promises_1.2.0.1   ps_1.6.0           R6_2.5.1           rappdirs_0.3.3     RColorBrewer_1.1.2
  Rcpp_1.0.7         rlang_0.4.12       rmarkdown_2.14     rsconnect_0.8.25   rstudioapi_0.13    rvest_1.0.0        sass_0.4.0        
  scales_1.1.1       selectr_0.4.2      shiny_1.6.0        sourcetools_0.1.7  stats_4.1.0        stringi_1.7.5      stringr_1.4.0     
  svglite_2.0.0      sys_3.4            systemfonts_1.0.2  tibble_3.1.6       tinytex_0.32       tools_4.1.0        utf8_1.2.2        
  utils_4.1.0        vctrs_0.3.8        viridisLite_0.4.0  webshot_0.5.2      withr_2.4.3        xfun_0.31          xml2_1.3.2        
  xtable_1.8-4       yaml_2.2.1
```

Comment: If you look at the html produced when `self_contained = true` you see the font-awesome css **is** included. But for the icons to appear they also need the svg/ttf/eof file. Along the `css` folder there is a `webfonts` folder, in this case in couldfare. The css file is just a class reference for each icon, the graphic information for the icon is actually in the svg/ttf/eof file.  I have not been able to figure out how to include these documents (or parts of them) inline in an html document, but I wanted to share what I know so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, rmarkdown is including the font-awesome css but not the graphic files. Therefore, when `self_contained = true` you don't see the images. The font-awesome css file looks for the images in the "webfonts" folder where it's sourced. At the bottom of the css file you'll find `@font-face {src: url(../webfonts/fa-regular-400.eot);`.

When rmarkdown makes a `self_contained` file, it converts images to base64 to load them directly into the html of the document. You could do the same for the icons you are using.

The solution below just adds a `background-image` (base64 encoded) to the font-awesome classes already in use. You can add the code anywhere in the page; for testing, I added it right below your css link in the footer. **Note:** below I truncated the base64 strings for brevity.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .fa-github-square:before {
    content: "\a0\a0\a0\a0";
    background: no-repeat url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0ia ... ")!important;
    }
    .fa-github:before {
    content: "\a0\a0\a0\a0";
    background: no-repeat url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDo ... ")!important;
    }
    .fa-globe-asia:before {
    content: "\a0\a0\a0\a0";
    background: no-repeat url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53 ...")!important;
    }
    .fa-envelope:before {
    content: "\a0\a0\a0\a0";
    background: no-repeat url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0ia ...")!important;
    }
    .fa-user:before {
    content: "\a0\a0\a0\a0";
    background: no-repeat url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0i ... ")!important;
    }
  </style>
```

I used the path of least resistance to get the base64 image strings:

1. I downloaded the "free for web" [zip file from font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v5/download)
2. I grabbed individual icons of interest from the "svgs" folder
3. I included an `<img src="github.svg" />` in a temporary `self_contained` rmarkdown to get the base64 encoded string for each of the svg files (you can use base64 online encoders instead).
4. I grabbed the encoded strings from the built html file and put them in the code above.

**To note:** The `self_contained` file is very large because it contains all the jquery, bootstrap, and font-awesome css/js files. And we just made it even larger! It's 5.2 MB in my machine without anything else except the little icons! If this was my project, I would consider not loading the font-awesome css and instead copy the few css lines that are pertinent to the icons I was using.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed investigation as well as the solution! The base64 method seems taking a detour, yet it works (and greatly reduces file size). Are there any reasons to add `!important`? I do not see other CSS files that will override the icons.

Comment: Ah, you you don't need `!important` in this solution, it's left over from trying to use `content` instead of `background`.

Comment: I [read](https://css-tricks.com/probably-dont-base64-svg/) this solution is not optimal. It's better if you include the SVG data info instead. See [Optimizing SVGs in data URIs](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/optimizing-svgs-in-data-uris) to make crossbrowser compatible uris. It may not matter in this case, but wanted to add a note since this is public.

Comment: Not suggesting this as a solution, because what's written above is much better, but this tweet shows how any data can be included in the generated document if desired: https://twitter.com/pandoc_tips/status/1533719290289041408